# How to use Switch Case statement in arrow function component?

Tags: reactjs

I have 3 different content components , I want to use Switch Case statement to put in my arrow function component, how could I do this?

```
switch(Pama) {
        case 1: 
            return <component1/>
            break;
        case 2:
            return <component2/> 
            break;
        case 3:
            return <component3/>
            break;
 }

const Card = () => {
    const [hidden, setHidden] = useState(true);
    return (
        <>
            { hidden &&  
            <Card_Container >
                I want to put the return component here
            <Card_Container>
            
            }
        </>   
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const foo = () => {
 switch(condition) {
  case 1:
   return something;
  case 2:
   do something
   break;
  default:
   return something when all case fail;
 }
}
```

> Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work you just have to put the Switch Statement inside a function and call that function inside the JSX

Example:

```
const RenderComponent=(Param)=>{
   switch(Param) {
          case 1: 
          return <Component1/>
          case 2:
          return <Component2/> 
          case 3:
          return <Component3/>
          default:
          return <DefaultComponent />
        }
   }
       
       const Card = () => {
           const [hidden, setHidden] = useState(true);
           return (
               <>
                   { hidden &&  
                   <Card_Container >
                       {RenderComponent(1)}
                   <Card_Container>
                   
                   }
               </>   
           );
       }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks , but i tried this before I post my question , and it's not working. (I got "param is undefined "). Then I went back to read the reference and I found out , we have to pass in an arrow function when we want to pass in param. ( The page is loaded now , but the component is still not pass in.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following sample:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const switchComponent = ({ switchParam }) => {
  let component;
  switch (switchParam) {
    case 1:
      component = <div>component1</div>;
      break;
    case 2:
      component = <div>component2</div>;
      break;
    case 3:
      component = <div>component3</div>;
      break;
    default:
      console.log("Unknwon switch param: ", switchParam);
  }
  return component;
};

export default function Demo() {
  const [hidden, setHidden] = useState(true);
  const [switchParam, setSwitchParam] = useState(1);
  const randomSwitchParam = () => {
    const randomNumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 3);
    console.log(randomNumber);
    setSwitchParam(randomNumber);
  };
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={randomSwitchParam}>Random Switch Param</button>
      {hidden ? <div>{switchComponent({ switchParam })}</div> : null}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```